# Recursive multiple relationships

Tags: recursion, neo4j, cypher

I'm attempting to recursively perform alternate match statements with 2 specific relationships.
For example, Pets are owned by a Person.  Pets LIKE other people (not owner)  Those people have pets owned by them, who like other people etc.

```
match (n.Person {id.123})<-[r.OwnedBy]-(p.Pet)  Return n, r, p
match (p.Pet {id.123})-[r.Likes]->(n.Person)  Return p, r, n
```

Notice the directional relationships involved - #1 is backwards, #2 is forwards.

What I want to do is to, given a person(id),
1. Display pets [OwnedBy] this person(id)
2. Display people [Liked] by those pets
3. Display pets [OwnedBy] the people in 2.
etc. recursively

Independently, these Match statements work.  together, they do not.
I tried adding the 2nd match statement, using different variables, then it will go down 2 levels and stop.

In the real data set, there are dozens of nodes and relationships.  I'm trying to limit the display to a 'tree' view of only these 2 relationships/nodes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
match (n:Person {id:123})<-[:OwnedBy]-(p:Pet)-[:Likes]->(n2:Person)<-[:OwnedBy]-(p2:Pet)
return n, collect(distinct p) as pets, collect(distinct n2) as peopleLiked, collect(distinct p2) as petsOfPeopleLiked
```

Though if you're only interested in the graph display, this should work:

```
match path = (n:Person {id:123})<-[:OwnedBy]-(p:Pet)-[:Likes]->(n2:Person)<-[:OwnedBy]-(p2:Pet)
return path, n, p, n2, p2
```

You can also utilize [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/). This can handle showing these paths, using only these two types of relationships:

```
match (n:Person {id:123})
call apoc.path.expandConfig(n, {relationshipFilter:'<OwnedBy|Likes>'}) yield path
return path
```

Comment: I tried the 2nd suggestion (as I am indeed only interested in the graph display.  Interestingly, it showed 
1) only the nodes where BOTH relationships related for (n), and 
2) went 2 levels deep then stopped.  I need it to be recursive. 
VERY much appreciate the help.  thoughts?

Comment: That's interesting, this procedure is meant for continuous traversal, only traversing incoming :OwnedBy and outgoing :Likes relationships, with no cap. Can you provide a query to generate a sample graph?

Comment: I tried the APOC method as well - once I installed APOC correctly(!!) it did seem to do what I wanted, though I can't tell if the recursion is working accurately yet.  More testing required.  THANK YOU x billions!

Comment: So using the 2nd option, it appears that the recursion is indeed working, however, like I mentioned, it's only displaying nodes where BOTH relationships are applicable on the first level, while the APOC method shows all nodes (either-or relationship).  Thoughts on that?

Comment: Right, my mistake, I was mentally lumping the first two as approach 1, since those are going to be limited in their depth, so when you said the 2nd option I thought you meant the APOC approach. You are correct, only the APOC approach will continue traversing the given relationships at any depth.